# Setting ImageView at certain positions in a ListView based on CheckBox

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox

So I have a List View that when you click on a row it opens up a new activity. In the new activity there's a checkbox. If you check the check box and then go back to the listview activity it should set a checkmark next to the list view item that was initially clicked.

Whats happening right now is when I check the checkbox and return to the listview every row has a checkmark next to it regardless of which row the checkbox was checked from.

heres my mainactivity with the listview and on click listener that starts the second checkbox activity

```
        //fill list view with xml array of routes
    final CharSequence[] routeListViewItems =    getResources().getTextArray(R.array.routeList);


    //custom adapter for list view
    ListAdapter routeAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, routeListViewItems);
    final ListView routeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.routeListView);
    routeListView.setAdapter(routeAdapter);

    routeListView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    int listViewItemPosition = position;
                    CharSequence route = routeListViewItems[position];
                    int imageId = (int) image.getResourceId(position, -1);
                    if (route.equals(routeListViewItems[position]))
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), RouteDetails.class);
                        intent.putExtra("route", routeDetail[position]);
                        intent.putExtra("imageResourceId", imageId);
                        intent.putExtra("routeName", routeListViewItems[position]);
                        intent.putExtra("listViewItemPosition", listViewItemPosition);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            }
    );
}
```

then heres what im passing from the second activity back to the listview activity

```
 @Override ///////for back button///////
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
            ////////sets checkmark next to listview item//////
            if (routeCheckBox.isChecked())
            {
                Intent check = new Intent(RouteDetails.this,MainActivity.class);
                check.putExtra("checkImageResource", R.drawable.checkmark);
                check.putExtra("listViewItemPosition", listViewItemPosition);
                startActivity(check);
            }
}
```

and heres back in my listview activity where I recieve the info from my checkbox activity and set the checkmark

edited to include full adapter class
edited to include code that I found to solve my issue!

```
        class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> {

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, CharSequence[] routes) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_row ,routes);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater routeInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = convertView;
        if(customView == null){customView = routeInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);}

        CharSequence singleRoute = getItem(position);
        TextView routeText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.routeText);
        routeText.setText(singleRoute);

       /////////////set check mark/////////////
        ImageView checkImageView = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.checkImageView);

        int checkImageResourceId = ((Activity) getContext()).getIntent().getIntExtra("checkImageResource",0);

        int listViewItemPosition = ((Activity) getContext()).getIntent().getIntExtra("listViewItemPosition",0);

        /////my solution was just setting where listviewitemposition == position in my getview method//////
        if (listViewItemPosition == position)
        {
        checkImageView.setImageResource(checkImageResourceId);}
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
  return customView;
    }
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: Create an entity (sya Route) with two attributes (Say name and checked:boolean) and a your custom adapter according to this entity. Implement the logic in getView method of your adapter to show and hide the checkbox according to the 'checked' value.

Comment: Is there anyway you could post an example with code? I'm really new to programming and it would be much easier visually.

Comment: Please paste more from the activity "where I recieve the info from my checkbox activity and set the checkmark"

Comment: hey I edited my original post to include the full adapter class where the checkmark needs to be set.

Comment: hey I solved my question it was super simple idk how I didn't notice it before

Answer (score 0):

The solution was I just needed use an if statement to set listviewItemPosition == position in my getView method

```
  /////my solution was just setting where listviewitemposition == position in my getview method//////
    if (listViewItemPosition == position)
    {
    checkImageView.setImageResource(checkImageResourceId);}
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
```